# Replacing shower surround

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

My hallway bath tub has these really thin glue-on walls that seem in OK condition, except for being cheap looking and needing to be reattached/caulked in certain places. Can I remove these panels and use newer, thicker glue on panels (1/4") on the existing walls if they're in good condition?

I'm not sure what kind of wall is behind the panels, but thinking it's drywall or greenboard. Home was built custom in the 1990s, but they either went with cheaper finishes at the end or the next owner did an inexpensive update (unlikely though). Bath renovation is probably 5+ years down the road, so looking for a mid-term solution as we have another bath we plan to reno first.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be feasible.

You'll need to get the spout and trim off, and you'll probably want to use that part of the old surround to help getting the holes in the right place on the new surround.

If the wall behind is not in good shape you can do it over in water-resistant drywall before applying the new surround, letting the surround hide the joints (should be possible if there's no obvious wall issue outside the surround now.)

*I once bought a set of panels based on price, and hauled them right back to the store to return when I opened the package (they were unbelievably thin, and of course the display set was mounted too high to touch at the store) and spent twice as much on a better set. So I understand why you're doing this.*